# Show that mapping is linear and compute the inverse

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

Task:
(i) show that f is linear
(ii) show that the inverse function of f does exist
(iii) compute the inverse function
(iv) check that this is really the inverse

I want to show, that

$$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 ; f(x,y,z) = (x+y,x-y,2z)$$ is linear.

It is enough to show, that $f$ can be written via $Ax$ with an $3 \times 3$ Matrix A. For this purpose we take a look at the basis vectors under $f$.

$$f(\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}) =\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} ; f(\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}) =\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} ; f(\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}) =\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

therefore the Matrix A is

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $$.

Now we have

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\y \\z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x+y \\ x-y \\ 2z \end{pmatrix}  $$

So $f$ is linear.

When i want to see if $f$ has an inverse function i can show, that $det(A) \neq 0$ which implies that f is invertible.

$$ det(A) = -4 $$ so an inverse function $f^{-1}$ must exist.

If i apply gauss algorithm to the extended matrix

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right) $$

i get $$A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}  1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 1/2 & -1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix} $$.

Now the inverse function

$$f^{-1}(x,y,z) = A^{-1} \cdot (x,y,z)^T = (0.5x+0.5y, 0.5x-0.5y,0.5z)^T$$

To show that $f^{-1}$ is really the inverse of f, one have to proof, that

$$ f^{-1}(f(x,y,z)) = (x,y,z) = 0.5x+0.5y+0.5x-0.5y, 0.5x+0.5y-0.5x-(-0.5y), 0.5*2z = (x,y,z)$$

and also

$$f(f^{-1}(x,y,z)) = (x,y,z) = 0.5x+0.5y+0.5x-0.5y, 0.5x+0.5y-0.5x-(-0.5y),2*0.5z = (x,y,z) $$

so $f^{-1}$ is really the inverse of f.

Is everything correct?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine.

An alternative to compute the inverse:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1  \\ 1 & -1  \end{bmatrix}^{-1} & \\ & 2^{-1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -\frac12\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1  \\ -1 & 1  \end{bmatrix} & \\ & 2^{-1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}  0.5 & 0.5 & 0  \\ 0.5 & -0.5   & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0.5\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. Depending on what you know about linear maps and their inverses it might be enough to check just one of $f^{-1}\circ f$ and $f \circ f^{-1}$ being equal to the identity.